# Store multiple matrices (GSL) in an map

Tags: python, c++, dictionary, matrix, gsl

I have multiple matrices that I would like to store in some c/c++ object. I am still very new to c/c++ but I have been told this is one way of doing this.

1. Create a map
2. Store matrices at the keys of the map

Here is an almost [working MWE](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Example-programs-for-matrices.html) (were it working I would not need to ask this question):

```
#include <map>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>

int
main (void)
{
  int i, j; 
  std::map<int,double> test;
  gsl_matrix * m = gsl_matrix_alloc (10, 3);

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      gsl_matrix_set (m, i, j, 0.23 + 100*i + j);
  // store in map
  test[1] = m;
  gsl_matrix_free (m);

  return 0;
}
```

I become uncertain (and an error is raised) by this line:

```
std::map<int,double> test;
```

because `gsl_matrix` is a structure, and that I believe makes this incompatible with what I want to to do. The error reads:

```
cannot convert gsl_matrix* to std::map<int, double>::mapped_type {aka double} in assignment
```

To be precise what I want to do is similar to python where we can just store objects into dictionaries like so:

```
import numpy as np
test = {}
test['a'] = np.array([[1,2],[2,3]])
test['b'] = np.array([[1,2],[3,3]])
test['c'] = np.array([[1,3],[5,3]])
test['d'] = np.array([[1,5],[6,3]])
.
.
.
```

How is this best replicated with `gsl`?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm not a C++ programmer!

However I'm pretty sure what you want to do is to specify the value of the map as a `gsl_matrix *`. The following compiles without any errors, however I think you might need to implement the `std::map` operators.

```
#include <map>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>

int
main (void)
{
        int i;
        int j;
        std::map<int, gsl_matrix *> test;

        gsl_matrix * m = gsl_matrix_alloc (10, 3);

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                        gsl_matrix_set(m, i, j, 0.23 + 100*i + j);
                }
        }
        // store in map
        test[1] = m;
        gsl_matrix_free(m);
        return 0;
}
```

Then to compile:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

I hope this helps!